# pointer array returns negative values

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the arithmetic mean of the digits of a number from a number array.
I'm trying to use dynamic memory allocation and pointers.
I can't think of anything faster or better.

```
void media_cifrelor(int *p, int &x)
{
    int *w = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while (*(p + i) != 0)
        {
            k++;
            *(w + i) += *(p + i) % 10;
            *(p + i) /= 10;
        }
        *(w + i) /= k;
        cout << *(w + i) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//p1.txt
// 7
// 12 231 9012 34 8123 22 507

int main()
{
    ifstream fisier("p1.txt");

    int n, *v;

    v = citire(fisier, n); // int *citire(ifstream &fisier, int &x)
    cout << "n= " << n << endl;

    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //     cout << *(v + i) << " ";
    // }
    cout << endl;

    media_cifrelor(v, n);

    return 0;
}
```

`cout << *(w + i) << " ";` returns random negative values on each run and I do not understand where is the mistake.

Reading from file function:

```
int *citire(ifstream &fisier, int &x)
{
    if (fisier.is_open())
    {
        int *p;
        fisier >> x;
        // cout << "x= " << x << endl;
        p = new int[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            fisier >> *(p + i);
            // cout << *(p + i) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the elements of the allocated `w` array, so each starts off with an arbitrary/random value. To fix this, set each of the `*(w + i)` elements to zero before you start accumulating the sums of the digits:

```cpp
void media_cifrelor(int *p, int &x)
{
    int *w = new int[x]; // Note: this memory is NOT zero-initialized!
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        *(w + i) = 0;    // ... so, we need to zero each value before summing.
        while (*(p + i) != 0)
        {
            k++;
            *(w + i) += *(p + i) % 10;
            *(p + i) /= 10;
        }
        *(w + i) /= k;
        cout << *(w + i) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] w; // Note: Don't forget to release the allocated memory!
}
```

As noted in the comments, you could zero the elements of the `w` memory block by adding an empty initializer list:

```cpp
    int* w = new int[x]{};
```

Better still, avoid 'old-style' `new[]` and `delete[]` operators and use: `std::vector<int> w(x, 0);`.

Comment: `new int[x]{};` or even `std::vector<int> w(x);` (to avoid memory leak).

Comment: but in fact, we don't need array anyway, `int w = 0;` after `int k = 0;` might be sufficient (and replace `*(w + i)` by `w`).

Comment: Also, using `std::unique_ptr` should be preferred over manual `delete`.

Comment: @SergeyA But, if using the STL is considered, then `std::vector` is better still, I feel.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that I have to initialize. Also, there is a `p = new int[x];` inside `int *citire(ifstream &fisier, int &x)` that doesn't' get deleted because I have to return it. Is that ok ? And since I assign `v = citire(fisier, n);` is `v` now of type `int[];` since  `p = new int[x];` ? How do I delete `v` at the end of `main` ? Do I use `delete v;` or `delete[] v;` ?

Comment: @Jorje12 when a function returns a pointer to memory that it allocated, then it *must not* `delete[]` that block! That is then up to the calling module to do, when *it* has finished with the memory. On your second point, `v` is a valid `int*` pointer - that is the type returned by `new int[x];`. But you can also use that pointer in 'array-style' expressions, like `v[3]`, rather than `*(v + 3)`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Why did I have to initialize `w` inside `void media_cifrelor(int *p, int &x)` but I did not have to initialize `p = new int[x];` inside `int *citire(ifstream &fisier, int &x)` or `int *v;` inside `main` ?

Comment: @Jorje12 In the case of the `p` array (in the `citire` function), you aren't using the 'random' initial values. You are, rather, directly assigning them in the `fisier >> *(p + i);` line. So, what was initially there just gets overwritten. However, in the case of the `w` array, you are assuming that it starts off at zero, then adding to it with the `+=` operator.